# unable to upload the project in Sonarqube while running sonar-runner

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 lts, Os type 32-bit, SonarQube 4.5.2, Sonar-runner 2.4, java version "1.7.0_65"

While Running Sonar-runner in terminal it Shows Following Error:

```
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_65 Oracle Corporation (32-bit)
Linux 3.13.0-24-generic i386
INFO: Runner configuration file: /home/musaddiq/Documents/Sonar/sonar-runner-2.4/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /home/musaddiq/Documents/SonarTest/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /home/musaddiq/Documents/SonarTest/./.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.5.2
10:44:50.726 INFO  - Load global referentials...
10:44:51.192 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 470 ms
10:44:51.210 INFO  - User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
10:44:51.230 INFO  - Install plugins
10:44:51.498 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
10:44:51.535 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
10:44:54.369 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
10:44:57.521 INFO  - Load project referentials...
10:44:57.673 INFO  - Load project referentials done: 152 ms
10:44:57.674 INFO  - Load project settings
10:44:58.599 INFO  - Loading technical debt model...
10:44:58.649 INFO  - Loading technical debt model done: 49 ms
10:44:58.652 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
10:44:59.218 INFO  - -------------  Scan SONARTEST1
10:44:59.242 INFO  - Load module settings
10:44:59.495 INFO  - Language is forced to java
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 10.333s
Final Memory: 13M/199M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'java'
ERROR: 
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
root@EIT-A21:/home/musaddiq/Documents/SonarTest# exit
exit
```

Using `sonar-runner -e`

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'java'
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: have you configured a java profile on the server ?

Comment: Can you help me how to configure java profile on the server?

Comment: can you re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch and post the contents

Comment: I am already Having java version "1.7.0_65"

Comment: you have java, but sonar needs a java plugin - so that it can analyse java projects. But If I m correct java pugin comes by default in sonar, Can you post the content after running it with -e switch

Comment: While Using Sonar-runner -e

Comment: Can you post the contents of the (server) directory ``$SQ_HOME/extensions/plugins``? Did you migrate from a previous version?

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that you have the java plugin installed 
http://qualilogy.com/en/sonarqube-upgrade/
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin